# Access lvel on azure AD for application registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

What level of access is required on azure active directory if someone wants to register the app? or how to get access to azure active directory and what kind of access levels available in general?

Thanks,
Bhupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the specific user account.

If the `USER TYPE` of your account is a `member`, and your tenant -> navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `User settings` -> `Users can register applications` is set to `Yes`, then you will be able to register the app. If this option is set to no, then only users with an [administrator role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles) may register these types of applications.

If the `USER TYPE` of your account is a `guest`, and `User settings` -> `Manage external collaboration settings` -> `Guest users permissions are limited` is set to `No`, then you can also register app. Otherwise, you can't. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#member-and-guest-users) here.

Comment: Great, Thanks for the inputs @Joy Wang

Comment: Yes. I could not try above options yet due to limited access however I think it clarifies what I looking for. Thanks for the answer.